# How to find paths of adjacent equal elements in grid

Tags: algorithm

I have a grid of numbers. I want to find all sequences of more than one adjacent equal elements in the grid. Here is an example:

```
1  3  5  2  3
3  4  5  2  1
1  5  5  2  5
4  5  2  2  5
4  1  2  2  5
```

in this example, I'm looking a way to find the sequences of 5 and 2 (not that there should be two sequences of 5):

**5.1**

```
x: 2 / y: 0
x: 2 / y: 1
x: 2 / y: 2
x: 1 / y: 2
x: 1 / y: 3
```

**5.2**

```
x: 4 / y: 2
x: 4 / y: 3
x: 4 / y: 4
```

**2**

```
x: 3 / y: 0
x: 3 / y: 1
x: 3 / y: 2
x: 3 / y: 3
x: 3 / y: 4
x: 2 / y: 3
x: 2 / y: 4
```

I tried to put the matrix in a binary tree. Something like this:

```
Node (0x0)
  value: 1
  right: Node (1x0)
            value: 3
            right: Node (2x0)
                      value: 5
                      right: Node (3x0)
                      down: Node (2x1)
            down: Node (1x1)
                     value: 4
                     right: Node (2x1)
                     down: Node (1x2)
  down: Node (0x1)
            value: 3
            right: Node (1x1)
            down: Node (2x0)
```

[image]
and then tried to recursively walk the nodes and find the sequences, but it didn't work for some reason. I will debug it and maybe will find a way to do it, I'm just asking if there's some well-known algorithm for such thing or it's not a trivial task?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are interested in finding the *connected components* of a graph whose nodes are the grid cells and whose edges connect the adjacent cells that contain the same value.

Comment: "... but it didn't work for some reason" -- what didn't work? You've posted the exepcted results, but what did you actually get? (My guess is that you need to mark the cells that you have processed as visited somehow.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

This will become much simpler if you connect *only* those cells with the same value.  There should be no other edges in your graph.  Then, it's simply a matter of counting the number of nodes in each sub-graph.